# receive multiple char input from a single line in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a stack data structure in java using arrays. The problem is when I try to push the users char input it doesn't display. The problem is with this code.

```
public static void preSuf(Stack stack) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the values");



       while(key.hasNext()){    
          char c = key.next().charAt(0);
          stack.push(c);
        }



}
```

When I change the  `while(key.hasNext())` to `if(key.hasNext())` it works but it only prints one time and doesnt itterate. How can I fix this problem thank you.

Edit: Here is the whole code

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stack {

    private int top;
    private char[] container;
    private int size;
    public static int pos = 0;

    // constructor
    public Stack(int N) {
        container = new char[N];
        size = N;
        top = 0;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return (size == top);
    }

    public void push(char string) {
        if (!isFull()) {
            container[top] = string;
            top++;
        } else {
            return;
        }

    }

    public int pop() {
        int drop;
        drop = container[top - 1];
        container[top] = 0;
        top--;
        return drop;
    }

    public int peek() {
        int drop2;
        drop2 = container[top - 1];
        return drop2;
    }

    public void display() {

        for (int i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
            if (container[i] != 0) {
                System.out.print(container[i]);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void preSuf(Stack stack) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the values");



            while(key.hasNext()){    
              char c = key.next().charAt(0);
              stack.push(c);

            }



    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Stack stack = new Stack(3);
        preSuf(stack);
        stack.display();
        stack.display();
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Your code appears to be fine.  Each character is pushed onto the stack.

Comment: it doesn't print them I don know what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't written any code to actually print the contents of your stack.

You could write a loop after your `while` loop to iterate over the stack and print out each character.

You'll also need a way of exiting your while loop.  You can do this either with a special character, eg. `if(c == '.') break;` or you can just press Ctrl+Z.

EDIT:  Based on the edit to the question and the full code being presented, I think the suggestion of needing the extra loop is now redundant. You have that in `stack.display()`.  You just need to get out of your `while` loop.

Comment: No worries. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

1. you haven't determined when the loop should end.
2. you'd think if you press enter without entering anything the loop
   would break but that's not how `next` operates. if you press enter
   without entering anything or input data which consists of only whitespaces, `next` will block while waiting for input to
   scan, even if a previous invocation of `hasNext()` returned *true*.

the solution is to include a condition at which control should break out of the loop.